# Why won't my .css file show up in the public directory when building webpack.mix.js?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, debugging, webpack

I have my `.scss` file defined inside the `webpack.mix.js` file.  However, whenever I compile, the `.css` file isn't showing up in my public directory.  I tripled checked the spelling of the files as well as the file path so that isn't the issue.

This is the error I'm getting below when deployed to production:

```
File plus/public/css/build/partials/live/user-navigation-live.css not defined in asset manifest. (View: /usr/share/nginx/v-1-2021-05-11_10-38/resources/views/layouts/login.blade.php)
```

This is how it's defined inside `login.blade.php`

```
<link href="{{ Cdn::mix('plus/public/css/build/partials/live/user-navigation-live.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Here's how it's defined in the `webpack.mix.js` file:

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/partials/live/user-navigation-live.scss', 'public/plus/public/css/build/partials/live/');
```

Here's how I'm building:

```
npm run dev && composer dump-autoload
```

What could be the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

How does your config look like?

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test:
                    /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            // Prefer Dart Sass
                            implementation: require('sass'),

                            // See https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/804
                            webpackImporter: false,
                            sassOptions: {
                                includePaths: ['./node_modules', './vendor/']
                            },
                        }
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
});
if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

You will have to add a configuration like the one above to make it work. And why are you loading the file not with the `asset()` helper? `mix()` will only work if you have versioned files.

Comment: Interesting.  What do you mean by versioned files?  I've always done it the way I've illustrated in my original post with no issues.  This issue for me came up out of no where.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting